# Nginx secure link only giving 403

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up and use the nginx secure link in ubuntu, but in all tries, I'm always having the 403 error.

Here is my server config:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name server.test.com;


    location /t/ {
       alias /home/server/files/;
     }


    location /y {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    alias /home/server/files/;
    # set connection secure link
    secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
    secure_link_md5 "itsaSSEEECRET$uri$secure_link_expires$remote_addr";

    # bad hash
    if ($secure_link = "") {
        return 403;
    }

    # link expired
    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 410;
    }

    # do something useful here
}
}
```

And below is the python code to generate the link:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import calendar
import datetime

secret = "itsaSSEEECRET"
url = "/y/test.mp4"
ip = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

future = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
expiry = calendar.timegm(future.timetuple())

secure_link = f"{secret}{url}{expiry}{ip}".encode('utf-8')

hash = hashlib.md5(secure_link).digest()
base64_hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash)
str_hash = base64_hash.decode('utf-8').rstrip('=')

print(f"http://server.test.com{url}?st={str_hash}&e={expiry}")
```

I'm able to generate the MD5 and expire in python and PHP, but on any try, I always get the 403 response and the video cannot be played.

Any suggestion for what can be the problem or missed configuration?

Comment: I am meeting the same problem, you need to generate your hash using the url_encoded path (for example: `tést.zip` becomes `t%C3%A9st.zip`

However, having resolved this issue, nginx returns a 404 because it tries to open the file `t%C3%A9st.zip` instead of `tést.zip` on my side, I hope my comment helps you and we can both solve our issues

Comment: Solved my issue, posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the URL before hashing it to match nginx's hash:

Given this configuration:

```
    location /pdf/ {
        secure_link_secret supersecret;
        if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }

        rewrite ^/pdf/[^/]+/(.*) /secure/pdf/$1; # Note that I am not using $secure_link as the encoding will break the file path.
    }

    location /secure {
        internal;

        rewrite ^/secure/(.*) /$1 break;
    }
```

If your path is `/pdf/fichier encodé.pdf`

```
$ echo -n /pdf/fichier encodé.pdfsupersecret | openssl md5
(stdin)= 77868fa6bc076a359a58d992f2f7c274
```

`http://127.0.0.1/pdf/77868fa6bc076a359a58d992f2f7c274/fichier encodé.pdf` will return a 403.

```
$ echo -n fichier%20encod%C3%A9.pdfsupersecret | openssl md5
(stdin)= c99a4271efda31ff09f285bff1e70104
```

`http://127.0.0.1/pdf/c99a4271efda31ff09f285bff1e70104/fichier encodé.pdf` will work!